# How can I use .htaccess to force SSL except for one path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using my `.htaccess` file to force https on my site. This is what my `.htaccess` file looks like:

```
# SSL only
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !^https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

I am using DOMPDF to render a pdf and it fails using https. So, I would like to force https on *every* page *except* the request to the pdf file. If the request to the pdf file is made using https, it should be redirected to http only.

Looking around at a few SO threads about this, I have this so far but it isn't quite working.

```
# SSL only for all pages except pdf requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !^https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/listing\/pdf\/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/listing\/pdf\/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want to force any request made to `/listing/pdf?listingId=123` to be http only.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
# SSL only for all pages except pdf requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/listing/pdf
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^listing/pdf$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Don't forget to clear your browser cache before testing, since your previous attempts will likely be cached.

**Update**

Try this if you're not behind a reverse proxy:

```
# SSL only for all pages except pdf requests
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/listing/pdf
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^listing/pdf$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is getting close I think - I don't get a consistent 500 anymore - but when I click the link to my pdf, it is still remaining in https. My site will always be https, so I need to 301 to just http whenever that link is clicked.

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy? I'm assuming so since you're checking `X-Forwarded-Proto`, but that will only apply if you have a reverse proxy taking care of your HTTPS termination?

Comment: That's a great question - I don't know if I am or not. That's 110% of my struggle. This well above my skill level. What I started with was a guide from the KB on my hosting.

Comment: I added an update to try which is for a setup without a reverse proxy doing the HTTPS termination. See if that works for you.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help. I tried the bottom version, and get a "too many redirect" error. I still am unable to get the top version to work. I believe I _am_ using a proxy. "Web applications behind HTTPS Proxies, Load Balancers or CDNs" is what I found in my docs. IDK why my system is being so stubborn.

Comment: You can usually tell if you're behind a reverse proxy by examining the HTTP headers and see if they contain any added by the proxy. That bottom set of rules alone can't be creating a redirect loop, you must also have some other rules in place for that to be happening.